# Disabled not working

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

1. Not working :

   - `[disabled] = true` ,
   - `[disabled] = "isDisabled"`    -----ts > ( isDisabled=true)
   - basic html disabler also not wokring ----html > `disable`
   - `[attr.disabled] = true` ,
   - `[attr.disabled] = "isDisabled"` -----ts > ( `isDisabled=true`)

I'm trying to make same form for preview and update (preview should have disabled inputs), but my input in html fails to bind to typescript boolean.
In html I have a table with person.name, person.surname .... button(preview), button(update) both triggering the onSelect function and sending person + true/false.

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="osoba.ime" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled" name = "ime" type="text" id="ime">
```

and typescript function and property

```
isDisabled = true;

onSelect(o: Osoba, isView) {
    this.isDisabled = isView;
    console.log(document.getElementById('ime'));
    console.log(this.isDisabled);
    this.selectedOsoba = o;
}
```

log of this.isDisabled is valid

but log of the element doesn't even have disabled property

```html
<input _ngcontent-c5="" id="ime" name="ime" type="text" ng-reflect-name="ime" ng-reflect-model="Dusan     " class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

here's the whole html code

```
<form *ngIf="osoba">
  <div class="input">
    <label>Ime Osobe</label>
    <input [disabled]= "isDisabled" [(ngModel)]="osoba.ime" name = "ime" type="text" id="ime">
  </div>
  <div class = "input">
    <label >Prezime Osobe</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="osoba.prezime"  name = "prezime" type="text" id = "prezime" [disabled] = "isDisabled">
  </div>
  <div >
      <label >Jmbg Osobe </label>
      <input  [(ngModel)]="osoba.jmbg" name = "jmbg" type="text" [attr.disabled]= true >
    </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="submit" value="izmeni" (click)="updateOsoba()">
  </div>
</form>
<input id="disabledTest" type="text" value="nekiTekst" [disabled]= true>
```

the input which is out of the form is working , but all inputs in form and divs not working
what's the catch ?

Comment: try [attr.disabled] = "isDisabled"

Comment: Already tried that

Comment: tried even like this , but look the text highlighter isn't the same maybe that's a lead

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hmfkec

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић your code should work. `log` statement  contains `id` and your HTML has no `id` set how is it logging?

Comment: It's not the same because you don't write it the same, and Vidsual studio code regexes don't recognize what you are trying to do (the second one isn't valid HTML). Are you sure you are looking at the right input ? You wrote its name as "jmbg" but you inspect "ime" ...

Comment: sry i was copied wrong input , it looks like this , <input  [(ngModel)]="osoba.ime" [disabled]="isDisabled" name = "ime" type="text" id="ime">

Comment: Highlighter difference was because of the space so i'm back to nothing

Comment: `log of this.isDisabled is valid` is the value truly `valid`? You should use boolean value.¨

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When using `attr.disabled`, you have to supply the literal value, or omit the attribute altogether. Bear in mind that the disabled attribute in HTML disables an element that supports the attribute simply by being present.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="osoba.ime" [attr.disabled]="disabled?'':null" name="ime" type="text" id="ime">
```

Both of the following in HTML should result in an input being disabled...

```
<input disabled />
<input disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this :

```
 <input
    type="radio"
    id="primaryIPV6"
    value="2"
    [attr.disabled]="flagValue ? '' : null"
    formControlName="p_ip_type"
    (change)="optionalFn()">
```

Answer (score 3):

In the reactive form creation, you can add as below

```
this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [{value: '', disabled: true}],
});
```

the form value will be disabled