# Why does a disabled RouterLink still work?

Tags: angular-material2, angular9, angular-routerlink

## Problem

I have a problem with links, which are active, although their `disabled` attribute is set to `true`.

## Setup

Following this pattern from the [official documentation of Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview):

```
<a mat-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

I am building the navigation section of my app like this:

```
<nav>
    <a mat-button routerLink="/foo" [disabled]="true">Foo</a>
    <a mat-button routerLink="/moo" [disabled]="true">Moo</a>
    <a mat-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" [disabled]="true">Link</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

As shown in the picture, the links are indeed shown as inactive. However, only the `href-link` is trully disabled. The ones for the in-app navigation with `routerLink` still work and I am able to change the pages by clicking on them.

[image: Screenshot of the example app]

## Example

I have prepared an [example project on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inactive-links-problem) to demonstrate this issue.

How to make the disabled routerLinks inactive?

---

## Update 1

For the sake of the experiment I have substituted the `nav` with `mat-nav-list` and the `mat-button`s with `mat-list-item` like this:

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/foo" [disabled]="true">Foo</a>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/moo" [disabled]="true">Moo</a>
    <a mat-list-item href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" [disabled]="true">Link</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Now it works as expected, but the outlook is not the one I want to have.

I can also substitute the `a`-tag with a `button` and add a `click`-listener calling [`Router.navigate`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate), but as the title says, I would like to know *Why does a disabled RouterLink still work* and how to trully (not only visually) disable it.

---

## Update 2

Meanwhile I have reported it as a [bug](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19428) to Angular Material.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabled not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772278/disabled-not-working)

Comment: @GSerg, nope, it does not. _There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks._ It is a feature of `Angular Material`, hence the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but it seems angular material is for design only, meaning you are disabling the CSS on the tag. If you want to stop the router, I think you need to do it on the typescript side, make a function to check whether the button is or isn't disabled and navigate or not accordingly.

Comment: _angular material is for design only_ - no, it is not. It does not simply add or remove classes. It changes the behavior too. I have extended my example to prove this. With `href` the disabled state works as expected. With the in-app-navigation counterpart of it, `routerLink` - it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for this is to add, pointer-events: none to the css